# How to route System.Diagnostics.TraceSource logs through NLog in .NET Core

Tags: .net, nlog, .net-core

is there anyway to route System.Diagnostics.TraceSource logs through NLog in .NET Core? Using the NLog for .Net 4.5 we could setup NLog.NLogTraceListener in the app.config file as remonstrated in this post http://nlog-project.org/2010/09/02/routing-system-diagnostics-trace-and-system-diagnostics-tracesource-logs-through-nlog.html , but we dont have app.config in .net core anymore.

I've setup libraries that are outputting logs with TraceSource and I would like to route it to NLog targets.

Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Maybe add the current .config settings to the post ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It worked for me.

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using NLog;

// Add this at the start of your app, like in Program.Main()
Trace.Listeners.Add(new NLogTraceListener());

// Now you can do...
Trace.TraceInformation("This message should go through NLog");
```

Of course, you'll need to properly configure NLog (`NLog.config`) with the [targets you need](https://nlog-project.org/config/#targets) to see the messages.

**Beware of target using `xsi:type="Trace"`** as this will lead to StackOverFlow Exception.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found so far is to do it programmatically.

According to the example at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx,

original configuration

```
<source name="System.Net" switchName="SourceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
  <listeners>
    <add name="nlog" />
  </listeners>
</source>
```

would look like this:

```
static TraceSource ts = new TraceSource("System.Net");
SourceSwitch sourceSwitch = new SourceSwitch("SourceSwitch", "Verbose");
ts.Switch = sourceSwitch;
int idxConsole = ts.Listeners.Add(new NLog.NLogTraceListener());
ts.Listeners[idxConsole].Name = "nlog";
```

I din't test this with NLog, but I have with a custom trace listener and it worked for me.